# How to add a pandas Timedelta to a Timestamp for a specific business and working time range

Tags: python, pandas, date, python-datetime

I would like to do add a Timedelta of e.g. 6 hours and 30 minutes to a Timestamp. The result should only consider the specific working time between e.g. 8:00 (begin working time) and 16:00 (end working time) for all valid business days. When I try this with following code this will end up in the wrong end time.

```py
pd.Timedelta('06:30:00') + pd.Timestamp('2019-11-08 14:30:00')
Timestamp('2019-11-08 21:00:00')
```

The desired result has to be '2019-11-09 11:00:00' and not '2019-11-08 21:00:00'

Does someone know a good solution how to specify the business hours, so that I can add a Timedelta to a Timestamp and the results ends up in the right business hours range?

Thanks and best regards
md5sum

Comment: Are you working with a column of some data? One way to go around this is to mask where the timedelta to be added larger than the remaining time of the work day and handles them separately.

Comment: No not really I choose pandas just because they have a lot of classes which handle offsets for business dates [link] (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessHour.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessHour) I thought may be there is a package who handle this in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

```
time_ini=pd.Timestamp('2019-11-08 14:30:00')
delta=pd.Timedelta('6:30:00')

def calculate_date(time,delta,ini,fin):
    Sum=time+delta
    if Sum.hour>fin:
        Sum= time + pd.Timedelta(days=1,hours=ini+Sum.hour-fin-time.hour-1,minutes=60-time.minute-1,seconds=60-time.second)
    elif Sum.hour <time.hour:
        Sum=time+pd.Timedelta(days=1,hours=ini+(24-fin)+Sum.hour-1-time.hour,minutes=60-time.minute-1,seconds=60-time.second)
    if Sum.dayofweek >4:
        Sum=Sum+pd.Timedelta(days=7-Sum.dayofweek)
    return Sum
calculate_date(time_ini,delta,10,20)
```

Ouput

```
Timestamp('2019-11-11 11:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks, I've a question: `if Sum.hour>20` the 20 is that a constant value or has this also to be calculated by `ini` and `fin`? Thanks

Comment: is the ini and fin, see now

Comment: please,check now:)

Comment: But I get the wrong value, because the desired output should be 2019-11-09 14:00:00 and not 2019-11-09 01:00:00, if I assume that `ini` and `fin` are 10:00 respective 20:00 working time begin and end.

Comment: I forget change if Sum.hour>fin,  check now

Comment: `delta=pd.Timedelta('14:30:00'); calculate_date(time_ini,delta,8,16)` gives me `Timestamp('2019-11-09 21:00:00')` which is out of the working range. Is it also possible to consider the business days from Monday to Friday ? Because I saw right now that the 9th of Nov is a Saturday ;-)